# How to find all the occasions where array items start with a specific letter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, substring

I want to know if there is another solution to what I'm doing here:

```
$aArray = array(
            array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 10)
            array('Name' => 'Tomato', 'Count' => 23)
            array('Name' => 'Tree', 'Count' => 4)
            array('Name' => 'Potato', 'Count' => 44)
            array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 73)

//Generate string with the 'Name's'
$aNamesMain = [];
$nCounterMain = 0;
$aNamesMain = array_merge($aNamenMais, array_keys($aArray['Name']));

foreach($aNamesMain as $name) {
    // Check to see which items start with an A
    if (substr('$name', 0, 1) === 'A') { $nCounterMain++; }
}
```

So I want to know how many times an item is found in my array at the `'Name' =>` place that starts with a specific letter. `A` in this case. But as I got it to work now it's like I posted above, but isn't there a better way to achieve this?

Some array function or something, because I've been trying some from the PHP manual but can't seem to find a better solution right now.

Something so I won't have to use the `foreach` or get rid of the array merge.

If this is off topic and needs to be posted at the code review page let me know but I thought this is a programming related something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to solve this:

```
//your array containing the items.
$aArray = array(
    array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 10),
    array('Name' => 'Tomato', 'Count' => 23),
    array('Name' => 'Tree', 'Count' => 4),
    array('Name' => 'Potato', 'Count' => 44),
    array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 73)
);

//the character or string you want to search.   
$startWithChar = 'A';

//get all items of the array starting with the specified character or string.  
$newArray = array_filter($aArray, function($v) use ($startWithChar) {
    return strpos($v['Name'], $startWithChar) === 0;
});

echo count($newArray); //2
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/EctCs7

Comment: Why not use `return $v['Name'][0] === $startWithChar;` ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I really like how this sollution looks. But im not really familiar with these anonymous functions. So what exactly does `$v['name']` do is the $v in this situation my $aArray?

Comment: @OliCrt - because the string could be empty (not in this example but possible).

Comment: @H.Brendan - `$v` is one of the values of the `$aArray` array. The `array_filter` run through all the values of  `$aArray` and `$v` is the current value, given to the callback (in this case the anonymous function).

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Thank you for the explanation, I kind of understand what happends here, also thanks for the quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is a good choice here.

```
$aArray = array(
            array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 10),
            array('Name' => 'Tomato', 'Count' => 23),
            array('Name' => 'Tree', 'Count' => 4),
            array('Name' => 'Potato', 'Count' => 44),
            array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 73),
    );

$startWithChar = 'A';
$newArray = array_filter($aArray, function($e) use ($startWithChar) {
    return substr($e['Name'], 0, 1) === $startWithChar;
});

echo count($newArray); // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, the other guy was a bit earlier,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) which reduce an array to an unique value, here the number of name starting whith letter 'A'.

```
$aArray = array(
    array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 10),
    array('Name' => 'Tomato', 'Count' => 23),
    array('Name' => 'Tree', 'Count' => 4),
    array('Name' => 'Potato', 'Count' => 44),
    array('Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 73)
);
$startWithChar = 'A';

$result = array_reduce($aArray, function($carry, $item) use($startWithChar){
    if(strpos($item['Name'], $startWithChar) === 0)
        $carry++;

    return $carry;
}, 0);

echo $result; //2
```

Comment: And doesn't create an useless array like array_filter, nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
//initial array
$x =[
    ['Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 10],
    ['Name' => 'Tomato', 'Count' => 23],
    ['Name' => 'Tree', 'Count' => 4],
    ['Name' => 'Potato', 'Count' => 44],
    ['Name' => 'Apple', 'Count' => 73]
];

$x = array_filter(array_column($x, 'Name'), function($key) {
    return (string) substr($key, 0, 1) === 'A' ? true : false;
});

//output array
echo count($x);  // should be 2
```